# Target an element with aura:id for CSS

Tags: aura, aura-attribute, aura-id

Can I use the `aura:id` attribute to target an element for styling?
If so, is better to use `aura:id` instead `id`?

Answer (score 2):

The `id` will let you get a reference to a specific DOM element. `aura:id` will let you get a reference to a [Component](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:Component) via `component.find("yourAuraId")`. Once you have a reference to the Aura component, you can call `.getElement()` or `.getElements()` to get the DOM that that component will render. It's probably  better to go through the framework APIs and use aura:id, though both will do the job to let you manipulate the specific DOM elements.

Note that you can also use the [`$A.util.addClass()`](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:Util) API to add a CSS class on a Component. There's also has, remove, and toggleClass APIs.

Comment: Thanks you for you and everyone else at SF for your continued involvement here. it is much appreciated.

Comment: @TrevorBliss but I think that `.getElement()` or `.getElements()` doesn't work with Service Locker enabled. Is it true?

Comment: @DarkSkull With LockerService enabled, `.getElement()` and `.getElements()` are available on components you have access to (your own namespace). Since these APIs give you direct access to the underlying DOM, LockerService restricts them for components from other namespaces. For other namespaced components you should go through the components public API, such as setting exposed aura:attributes or calling aura:methods.